# Trying to find story from magazine between 1976 and - cee-pee guns

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, novella

When I was too young, my mother got me a subscription to Analog or Asimov or another main sci-fi fantasy magazine - a little too advanced for her nerdy son at the time. But there was a story (after Star Wars) about a fellow who had a cat/tiger-like alien friend who swore a lot and they were captured by an evil queen.

The queen tries to seduce him and he breaks free, remembering that she liked to consume 'certain parts' of her former lovers. They steal her awesome spaceship with multiple missiles, guns, and something called "cee-pee guns" which I remember to this day and don't know if anyone else ever wrote 'cee-pee guns'. They blow up most of the enemy fleet but crash.. and the cat alien ends by swearing a lot.

This is what I remember.  I've lost the magazine over the decades and I would love to have those old magazines again. I was sure I'd recognize the cover but they all look alike on Ebay.

Can anyone identify this story?

Comment: Another thing I remember - they distracted the enemy troops by showing  a giant hologram of the Queen without clothes (taken earlier) - you can imagine why my teenage brain remembers that and not the author 8-)

Comment: Was the protagonist a pilot?  Was the felinoid companion female?  Good in a fight?  I don't remember the specific situation you're describing, but I recall a novel that was a series of escapades of that type...